# MySQL - Is it possible to use COUNT, GROUP BY and JOIN like this?

Tags: mysql, database

The below is one of my table, named board.

```
id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
board_name varchar(10) not null,
type varchar(10) not null,
article_id int unsigned,
title varchar(255) not null,
content text not null
```

And two types of data are stored in that table, article and reply.
Only reply type has a article_id; article type has only a null value in the article_id.

What I want to do is: 
1. Count the number of the reply for each articles.
2. Get info (title and content) of the top 5 article of the 1.

I can count the 1 like this:

```
select article_id, count(*) as count from board 
where article_id is not null group by article_id order by count desc limit 5;

+------------+-------+
| article_id | count |
+------------+-------+
|         12 |     7 |
|          3 |     5 |
|          6 |     3 |
|         11 |     2 |
|          1 |     1 |
+------------+-------+
```

Now, I know the top 5 articles' id.
But I have no idea how I can get the articles' info using these ids.
I searched and found that there is a join function, but can I use it for the same table? 
The result I expect is this:

```
+------------+-------+-------+---------+
| article_id | count | title | content |
+------------+-------+-------+---------+
|         12 |     7 |       |         |
|          3 |     5 |       |         |
|          6 |     3 |       |         |
|         11 |     2 |       |         |
|          1 |     1 |       |         |
+------------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Or should I find some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join a table with itself. But you will need to use table aliases and use it as prefix for column names.

```
select a.*, count(*) as count 
from board as r -- r is alias (reply)
join board as a on a.id = r.article.id
where r.article_id is not null
group by r.article_id
order by count desc
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve a call like this on a project a while back. What you have to do is nest a call in a join (see below).

```
SELECT b.title, b.content, b.article_id, b2.count 
FROM board b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT article_id, COUNT(id) AS count
    FROM board
    WHERE article_id IS NOT null
    GROUP BY article_id
) b2 ON b2.article_id = b.id
ORDER BY b2.count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you, too. Your answer also helped me a lot!